# Table per type in fluent nhibernate using IAutoMappingOverride

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is it possible to create a Table Per Type mapping using fluent nhibernate with only the IAutoMappingOverride interface? I really want to avoid writing out a full mapping for my models.

Answer (score 0):

Not using `IAutomappingOverride` but with AutomappingConfiguration

```
class MyAutomappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool IsDiscriminated(Type type)
    {
        return false; // or whatever classes it should discriminate instead of table per type
    }
}
```